# Google search engine displaying site title as "Web"

Tags: asp.net, seo, google-search, html-title

The title displays properly in all other search engines, it only does this with Google's search:

[image]

The site (www.ClearspanInc.com) has been up for awhile, and has had more than enough time to be crawled. We are using ASP.net.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title>******* - <%: Page.Title %></title>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">     
              <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
         </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Comment: Analytics has nothing to do with Google search or the crawler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside the @Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" %>
```

Or inside the Page_PreRender you can add Page.Title = "";

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
```

Comment: I see we already have the site title in the master page... <title>**** - <%: Page.Title %></title> and yet it still does not work properly :(

Comment: @SLaks Forgot to put the @

Comment: Can we get a link to your site

Comment: What do you see in the rendered source?

Comment: I'll see if I can provide a link. One second

Comment: That site appears to be down. Also I wouldn't post your email on a public thread.

Comment: ClearspanInc.com @ColinSchoen Apologies for the misinformation earlier.

Comment: I see that you have correctly set your title as each page title.

Ex: `Home Page` Did you make any changes to your listing in google webmaster tools? If not then just wait for google to index and reflect the changes.

Comment: @ColinSchoen The last time we updates was weeks ago... That would have been plenty of time for them to reflect the changes, correct? As I said, all other search engines display proper title, it is just Google.. I am not very familiar with Google's webmaster tools, I wiil look into it.